# How to execute processes in serial and in parallel using python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess, serial-processing

How can i create a process execution in serial fashion vs parallel fashion?

For example i want each process to execute the following python function:

```
def execute():
   time.sleep(random.randint(0,9))
```

If i run the processes like:

```
for process in process_list:
   process.run()
```

Given a scenario of only 2 processes in a **serial** fahsion i would expect the output of the program to be exatcly:

```
process 1 - start
process 1 - end
process 2 - start
process 2 - end
```

In a **parallel** scenario i would expect a possible output such as:

```
process 1 - start
process 2 - start
process 2 - end
process 1 - end
```

How can i replicate these two scenarios in python with a processing module?
By using `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` modules?

Answer (score 0):

Use the threading built in library.

Create your thread with

```
thread = threading.thread()
```

start it with

```
thread.start()
```

and then, within the thread's execution, call

```
 otherThread.join()
```

to form a sequential/serial queue in which the calling thread executes after the called thread.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html